# Adding 2 days to StartTime in my DB within WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql

```
"SELECT a.StartTime, a.ClientId, a.ServiceId, a.id, a.WhoEdit, a.EndTime, a.Confirmed, a.WhoBooked, a.AppointmentNote, c.ClientFirstName, 
                c.ClientLastName, c.ClientPhoneNumber, c.ClientAddress, c.ClientAddress2, b.BusinessName, b.BusinessAddress, b.BusinessAddress2, b.BusinessCity,
                b.BusinessState, b.BusinessZip, b.BusinessOwnerName, b.BusinessOwnerEmail, b.BusinessOwnerPhoneNumber, c.ClientCity, c.ClientState, c.ClientZip, s.ServiceName, s.ServicePrice, 
                s.ServiceLength, s.ServiceNote FROM appointments a 
            LEFT JOIN clients c ON a.ClientId = c.ClientId
            LEFT JOIN services s ON a.ServiceId = s.ServiceId
            LEFT JOIN business b ON a.BusinessId = b.BusinessId
            WHERE (a.Confirmed='false' OR a.confirmed='') AND a.StartTime<=DATE_ADD(a.StartTime, INTERVAL 2 DAY) ORDER BY b.BusinessName asc, a.StartTime desc"
```

I have the following query that is not working as expected. I want to grab the dates that are two days ahead from a.StartTime. However, I am getting dates from days ago. What should this query be?

StartTime is datetime.

[image]

Here are examples of the row in the DB.

[image]

Comment: You are not implementing a rule for the lower bound, only the upper bound.

Answer (score -1):

In that case, you need to adjust the logic in your WHERE clause to ensure you're comparing the StartTime with a date that is two days ahead. You can achieve this by adding 2 days to the StartTime using the DATE_ADD function. However, you should also consider the possibility that StartTime might have a time component, and you want to compare the dates only. You can achieve this by using the DATE function to extract only the date part. Here's how you can modify your query:

```
SELECT 
    a.StartTime, 
    ...so on
FROM 
    appointments a 
LEFT JOIN 
    clients c ON a.ClientId = c.ClientId
LEFT JOIN 
    services s ON a.ServiceId = s.ServiceId
LEFT JOIN 
    business b ON a.BusinessId = b.BusinessId
WHERE 
    (a.Confirmed = 'false' OR a.confirmed = '') 
    AND DATE(a.StartTime) <= DATE(DATE_ADD(DATE(a.StartTime), INTERVAL 2 DAY))
ORDER BY 
    b.BusinessName ASC, 
    a.StartTime DESC
```

In this modified query:

- DATE(a.StartTime) extracts the date part from StartTime.
- DATE_ADD(DATE(a.StartTime), INTERVAL 2 DAY) adds 2 days to the date
  part of StartTime.
- The WHERE clause compares the date part of StartTime to the date part
  of StartTime plus 2 days, ensuring you get appointments that are two
  days ahead from the StartTime.

Comment: `DATE_ADD` returns a full date again... don't modify StartTime before passing it to DATE_ADD, instead use DATE() on the return value of DATE_ADD...